# Firestore Chat Structure

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on chat feature in app, i've implemented chat rooms, and it works really good in structure

```
Chats[]->ChatID->Messages[]
```

but now I'm facing problem how to preserve chat headers. I mean Chat Members (Names, Photos)
and Last message with Timestamp

Could you share some tips please? :)

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can create a complete and functional Firestore Chat App.

Comment: You can check the following repo: https://github.com/AhnafMuttaki/firestore_chat